# How to translate the phrase "To mention" at the start of the sentence?

Tags: перевод

I'm translating a sentence, that starts like this:

> And **to mention** just one more of the catastrophic implications of “advanced” capital’s systemic development, we must bear in mind the prohibitively wasteful global ecological encroachment of our no longer tenable mode of social metabolic reproduction on the finite planetary world, with its rapacious exploitation of the non-renewable material resources and the increasingly more dangerous destruction of nature.

*Source*: Istvan Meszaros, [Structural Crisis Needs Structural Change](http://monthlyreview.org/2012/03/01/structural-crisis-needs-structural-change).

How do i translate the phrase “*to mention*” at the start of the sentence? Is the phrase “*to mention*” used in the beginning of the sentences as special stand-alone expression the same way “*not to mention*” is, and if so, what is its meaning? I know that “not to mention” is easily translated as “*не говоря о*”, but i'm not sure about this one.

Comment: Man, break this down. It sounds terrible in English, and when you translate this into Russian, you are adding 20-25% of volume.

Comment: @StasK I don't think the OP has an option to break this up.  He's dealing with somebody else's text.

Comment: If the OP is translating a text, it is his/her product now, and they can translate it as they see fit. Although if they want to maintain the heavy long-winded style of the author, sindikat can make it Dostoevsky-long :).

Answer (score 8):

In this case, *to mention* is not a stand-alone phrase/word.  Instead, you have one whole of *to mention just one more of the catastrophic implication*.  Therefore you need to look at this as a whole.  I would translate this particular sentence without translating it word-for-word:

> Еще одним катастрофическим следствием...

If you are intent on using something in place of *to mention*, I think *к тому же* or *вдобавок* (more colloquial) would be reasonable options:

> К тому же, еще одним катастрофическим следствием...
>   or
>   Вдобавок, еще одним катастрофическим следствием...

Finally, please note that I don't have the whole context: your specific context may require some other interpretation/translation of this phrase.

Comment: I like "ещё" better than "вдобавок"

Answer (score 4):

> To mention just one more of the catastrophic implication...

can be translated as:

> Касаясь еще одного катастрофического последствия ...

I think it's the most precise translation here, given that Russian infinitive clauses do not always function in the same way as English ones.

If the object of "mention" is a relatively short phrase, you can also translate it as "что касается". If "to mention X" is a stand-alone phrase, you can use "кстати":

> To mention the cats. My sister once had a cat who could open the fridge...
>   Кстати, о кошках. У моей сестры однажды был кот, который умел открывать холодильник...

Comment: Also, "касательно" (old style). "Что касательно ума, он целёхонек весьма"

Comment: "Что касается" тогда уж.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate it as "в контексте":

> В контексте ещё одного катастрофического последствия системного совершенствования "развитого" капитала, мы не должны забывать...

Answer (score 0):

to mention = говоря

And to mention just one more of the catastrophic implications...

Говоря о ещё одном из катастрофических последствий...

Comment: While _говоря_ can be used in this circumstances, the translation you provided has different meaning from the original.  If you want it to have the same meaning, it would have be _говоря еще об одном из катастрофических последствий_ (it's one implication, not one time speaking).

Comment: @Aleks Oh yes you're right